Mounting Hardware for Privacy Panel on Brick wall
I'm trying to add more privacy to this bathroom window.I found these panels and would like to not mount it flush against the brick. The last picture shows kind of what I'm looking to achieve. It doesn't have to be the exactly but something to where maybe they sit 2-3" off the wall. I don't know if a standoff mount is my best option but any suggestions would be greatly appreciate. There are 4 holes (1 in each corner to attach), its made of some poly material. I picked 3 of these up at lowes
I just don't want them to be flush so some more light can pass through as it is only window in bathroom.




Most windows are dirty with body oils/plain dirt.  A good cleaning with alcohol type cleaners might help film hold better.

@crip659 Yeah I tried numerous attempts with different films. The glass was completely cleaned before installation attempt. The window is textured as well. Also this was attempted on the inside part. That option isn't going to work so I'm going to try this if i can find a way to mount it away from the wall.

Do you own this home?

@Huesmann Yes 100% own the home. So i can make holes if needed :)

I would consider drilling holes in the brick face (not the mortar) and using metal (not plastic) expansion anchors.  Drill as close to the center of a brick as you can get—hopefully your screen frame has some adjustability.

@Huesmann yeah i planned to drill through the brick face. Just trying to find a bracket of some sort to bring it away from the brick 2-3 inches to allow a little bit more light through as apposed to screen being flush against the brick. I'll see what I can google. Thank you

@89fiveohgt window dimensions?  Worst case, you can buy some aluminum square tubing at Home Depot or equivalent.  Use a grinder or saw to cut triangular notches and bend the tubing into a hat shape.  Drill holes in the "brim" of the hat and use those to mount to the brick, attach the screen(s) to the top of the hat.

Thanks @Huesmann for the idea that worked.
@Huesmann response: buy some aluminum square tubing at Home Depot or equivalent. Use a grinder or saw to cut triangular notches and bend the tubing into a hat shape. Drill holes in the "brim" of the hat and use those to mount to the brick, attach the screen(s) to the top of the hat.
